# Как мне привязать QScrollArea к QLabel, чтобы все работало?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qss, qscrollarea

у меня не выходит вставить `QLabel` в `QScrollArea`. 
Форму делаю в *Qt Dtsigner*.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class DerNeXApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DerNeXApp, self).__init__()

        loadUi('gui.ui', self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)
        self.conversation_history = ""
        self.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)

    def on_button_click(self):
            self.conversation_history += f"Вы: {user_input}.\nDerNeX: {response_text}.\n\n"
            self.label.setText(self.conversation_history)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = DerNeXApp()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**gui.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>DerNeX</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="DerNeX">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>700</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>DerNeX</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>640</y>
      <width>581</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Accuratist.otf</family>
      <pointsize>16</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor" stdset="0">
     <cursorShape>IBeamCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>input</string>
    </property>
    <property name="whatsThis">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Enter your text&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="accessibleDescription">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="html">
     <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Accuratist.otf'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:10pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>580</x>
      <y>640</y>
      <width>61</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>send</string>
    </property>
    <property name="whatsThis">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Send&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(42, 42, 42);
image: url(:/gifs/icons8-up-50.png);
border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>641</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Accuratist.otf</family>
      <pointsize>15</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
image: url(:/gifs/965233-200(1).png);
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
    <property name="margin">
     <number>10</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>620</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>20</width>
      <height>641</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="send.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите сделать в форме, может выглядеть примерно так.

Обратите внимание:

- я полностью переписал в *Qt Designer* **модуль.ui**;
- стили я добавляю в `app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)`;
- `border-image: url(foto.jpg);` - это ваша фоновая картинка.

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class DerNeXApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DerNeXApp, self).__init__()

        loadUi('q1560582_gui222.ui', self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)
        self.conversation_history = ""
# ?      self.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        
        self.i = 1                                              # + для тестирования

    def on_button_click(self):
# ----> vvvvvvvvvv <----------------------------------------------------------- ???   
        user_input = self.textEdit.toPlainText()                # + 
        response_text = '12345 ' * self.i                       # +
# ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------------------- ???        
        self.conversation_history += f"Вы: {user_input}.\nDerNeX: {response_text}.\n\n"
        self.label.setText(self.conversation_history)
        
        self.i += 1                                             # +  для тестирования


Stylesheet = """
#label {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: transparent;               /* <---------------------------- */ 
}

#scrollArea {
    border-image: url(foto.jpg);                 /* <---------------------------- */ 
}

"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)                                          # +++
    
    main_win = DerNeXApp()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1560582_gui222.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>469</width>
    <height>458</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>10</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
        <property name="widgetResizable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>0</x>
           <y>0</y>
           <width>447</width>
           <height>316</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: transparent;</string>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <family>Calibri</family>
              <pointsize>16</pointsize>
              <italic>false</italic>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>111</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>100</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>100</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>100</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>PushButton</string>
           </property>
           <property name="autoRepeatDelay">
            <number>100</number>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: @neonexe  что не так?