Помогите с переносом интерфейса приложения с Figma на PyQt5
Здравствуйте я создал интерфейс своего лаунчера майнкрафт на Figma, но у меня не получается перенести интерфейс с Figma на PyQt5. Пожалуйста помогите мне с переносом интерфейса. Если что я использую Python 3.12.
Вот скрин интерфейса:

Пожалуйста помогите только те кто шарят в этом.

Представляю себе этот перенесенный ужастик (в смысле кода). Надо просто сесть и спроектировать по картинке.  Сам по себе вопрос меня немало удивил. Это что, сложный интерфейс, который программист, надумавший писать с использованием PyQt5, не может быстро воспроизвести? А что  дальше будет после того, в этот самом PyQt5? Надо ж ещё и какие-то действия писать.

neon exe, а что с вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560582

Мне нужно перенести интерфейс с figma на PyQt5 (Скрин интерфейса на Figma в картинке). Но когда я пытался перенести интерфейс у меня ничего не получилось :(
